# Alert Dialog Box - how to?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

In my project. I am using two Alert Dialog Box.The two alert dialogue box used in private methods. Private methods are `checkIn( )` and `checkOut( )`

In Main Activity, I am having One Button. Two functions for the Button. One Function is Check-In and another Function is Check out.

When I went to the Activity the Button Visible in Check-in. If I click the Button. It changes into Check out and Displays the Alert Dialogue `checkIn( )` private method.

If I refresh the Activity It will change into check-in.
what is my question how to get the Checkout Action when I refresh the activity.Can anyone Solve and give solution for this...

Thank you in advance. I attached the sample code below

```
public class Insert_DataSql extends AppCompatActivity {


    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    String formattedDate;
    WebConnection connectionClass;
    Button cin,cout;
    TextView dat,tim,adddre;
    Boolean flag=true;


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insertdata);
        connectionClass = new WebConnection();

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("LoginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//here we go getdata
        user name=sharedPreferences.getString("User name",null);

//Button Click able

cin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    buildAlertMessageNoGps();

                } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {


                    if (flag) {
                        getMyCurrentLocation();
                        CheckinButton();
                        flag =false;
                        Toast.makeText(Insert_DataSql.this, "True statement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dat.setText(date);
                        new Insert_data().execute("");//insert for button
                        //   tim.setText(formattedDate);

                    }
                    else{
                        flag =true;
                        getMyCurrentLocation();
                        CheckoutButton();
                        Toast.makeText(Insert_DataSql.this, "Wrong statement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dat.setText(date);
                        new Insert_data().execute("");
                        // tim.setText(formattedDate);
                    }
                                    }
            }
```

//Private methods for the Alert Dialogue box

```
      private void CheckoutButton() {
        if(flag == false ){
            cin .setText("Check Out Sucessfull");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Insert_DataSql.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Check Out Sucessfully");
            alertDialog.setMessage(adddre.getText());
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }

    private void CheckinButton() {
        if(flag == true ){
            cin.setText("Check Out");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Insert_DataSql.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Check In Sucessfully");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Have A Nice Day");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

define those variables:

```
    public static final String PREF_FLAG = "FLAG";
    private static String COUT = "cout";
    private static String CIN = "cin";
    private static String defaultFlagValue = COUT;
```

and add those methods :

```
    private String getFlag() {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_FLAG, defaultFlagValue);
    }

    private void setFlag(String flag) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_FLAG, flag);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

and update your code :

```
private void CheckinButton() {
        if (getFlag() == COUT) {

            ...

            setFlag(CIN);
        }

    }

private void CheckoutButton() {
        if (getFlag() == CIN) {

            ...

            setFlag(COUT);
        }
    }
```

and finally update tour `onClick` function

```
cin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                buildAlertMessageNoGps();

            } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {


                if (getFlag() == CIN) {
                    getMyCurrentLocation();
                    CheckinButton();
                    Toast.makeText(Insert_DataSql.this, "True statement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dat.setText(date);
                    new Insert_data().execute("");//insert for button
                    //   tim.setText(formattedDate);

                }
                else{

                    getMyCurrentLocation();
                    CheckoutButton();
                    Toast.makeText(Insert_DataSql.this, "Wrong statement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dat.setText(date);
                    new Insert_data().execute("");
                    // tim.setText(formattedDate);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you very much sir.I will check.

Comment: This code is working as once.if i refresh the activity it's not working